# Delphi: cursor over certain part of component

Tags: image, delphi, position, mouse, coordinates

Picture on the TImage is divided on a number of small rectangles and i need to check if user clicks on one of them. Basically, i need to create button on image without button itself. So, the question is: how to check if cursor is over a certain part of Image component? 
[image: Example]

Comment: Can your columns/rows vary in size? If so, it would be a much different approach than if they were always the same size. I would suggest that you look into creating your own custom control which encapsulates whatever functionality you need, rather than using an image to draw a grid and implementing it from within the form.

Comment: Add an OnClick event handler and call GetMessagePos inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `OnMouseDown` or `OnMouseUp` event handler to `TImage` and check `X` and `Y` params.